# How to Convert Table Into Columns R

Tags: r

How do I convert a datatables to columns, for example:

```
  AB CD EF JK LM
X 6  0  5  0  0
Y 0  7  0  0  0
Z 0  0  8  0  0 
A 0  0  0  9  0
B 0  0  0  6  10
```

to

```
      V1   V2   
 X    AB   6 
 X    EF   5
 Y    CD   7 
 Z    EF   8
 A    JK   9
 B    LM   10
 B    JK   6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to convert the 'data.frame' to 'matrix', `melt` it, and `subset` the 'value' that are not '0'.

```
 library(reshape2)
 subset(melt(as.matrix(df1)), value!=0)
```

Or

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 add_rownames(df1, 'rn') %>%
          gather(V1, V2, -rn) %>%
          filter(V2!=0)
```